# Connecting to an SFTP using Storage in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, php-7.2

I Stumbled upon (not sure if its unique) a very tricky situation , when I try to connect to an SFTP with invalid credentials or is not enabled.

The first time I try to connect to SFTP which is not available it throws me proper error message but If I try to reconnect to same SFTP within a minute or 2 it does not throw any exception, I tested the same via **php artisan tinker** of LARAVEL.

```
    function conectToSFTP()
    {
        $diskName = 'sftp_name';
        try {
            $disk = Storage::disk($diskName);
            $files = $disk->files('/');
            echo "connected to sftp";
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo "Unable to connect to SFTP " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

[image]

How can I get proper error message second time as well.
Due to some reason or based on some condition I have to call

```
Storage::disk($diskName);
```

twice.

I tried adding a time delay using

```
sleep(45);
```

but that didnt worked